# No Certificates are available provisioning portal

Tags: provisioning-profile, code-signing-certificate

Today I tried to upload a new version of my app, that uses Push Notifications, and XCode showed and error that I didnt have any valid Distribution profile.
When I logged in the Provisioning Profile I saw that ALL my Distribution Profiles had expired, even though the last one, the one I was using for this specific app, was only 2 weeks old.

I tried renewing the profile from XCode but it gives this error `No value was provided for the parameter 'certificateIds'.` So I tried to make another Distribution Profile, but when I do so it doesnt find any Certificate Available.
[image]

I try to do another certificate, clicking on that button, the certificate is created, it appears as a `APNs Production iOS` but when I go back it keeps saying there are no available Certificates.

So I have no idea what Im doing wrong, I recreated the CertificateSigningRequest and still nothing.
I downloaded and installed the `AppleWWDRCA` but I dont know what to do with that, I installed it and that's it.

Any ideas? Im completly lost.

Comment: Im still not able to create a Provisioning Profile from a Certificate that uses APNs, the only certificates that appear in the screen where I have to choose the certificate are the standard ones, not the APNS, any ideas? Did they change the way to create a Provisioning Profile, they did change the interface...

Comment: I am running into this same issue.  Trying to figure it out right now.

Comment: anyone find any solution?

Comment: It looks like it will only show certificates that are not listed as for Push Notifications, which doesnt make sense...
I waiting to test my app with Push Notifications in Production.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm experiencing the same issue. Did you found the solution ?

** EDIT **

I found the solution : I had created an APN certificate but the provisioning needed a classic dev / push certificate.

Comment: hi @Jackson , can you please elaborate about "classic dev/push certificate". I am not getting your point properly that how can you create it ?

Comment: To be honest I don't remember, sorry. I believe I just did a regular certif through the apple dev website. I may have done it from scratch but I'm not sure.

Comment: That's not a good answer I guess, the tutorial I've read said nothing of "did a regular certif through the apple dev website. I may have done it from scratch". It just started creating the provisioning profile and the certificate was there. I've been researching and many places show the same behavior, but the certificate is simply not appearing here.

Comment: You need to create a Development Certificate.  The first section of radio buttons shown when prompted with "What type of certificate do you need?"

Comment: this is what worked for me: open Xcode click xcode > preferences > Manage certificates > + in bottom left > ios distribution certificate. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 8):

I was able to solve this by creating a Distribution certificate.  I hadn't realized that my existing certificate was only marked as Development.  To do this I went into Xcode > Preferences > Accounts > View Deatils and then hit the refresh button at the bottom left.  This prompted Xcode to request a distribution cert for me.

Answer (score 6):

I also found this question, and was kinda confused with the answers ;)

But I figured it out: You need 2 certificates: For your app ID, you need to create a certificate for push notifications, an APN certificate (you can do this by clicking edit on your app ID, enable push notifications, and click "create certificate" for production). This will provide you with an certificate for your push notifications.

Secondly, you need to create a sign certificate (don't know if this is the right term), for your app. So you click on certificates, click on the + icon, choose app store, and follow the wizard.

Now you can create a new provisioning profile by clicking the + icon in the provisioning tab, and choose "App Store and Ad Hoc". Now you see your distribution certificate and you can create a provisioning profile for signing your app for production.

Comment: i created push certificate for development purpose but its not visible on provisioning. Do i need to created adhoc then only it will be visible on provisioning tab?

Comment: I am having same problem . So now by creating certificate this way, from which certificate should we create p12 file?

Answer (score 4):

For me the issue was that I didn't generate personal iOS Development certificate, and only had the APN certificate.

You need to generate this one from your XCode (XCode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details -> iOS Development Signing Identity)

[image: XCode iOS Development Certificate]

After that, my certificate was available to add during provision profile creating.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

ok i had the same problem but basically you just have to go back and create a standard iOS development certificate. Don't click the APN certificate. It worked for me

Answer (score 0):

For me this is worked. In the same window click on

create certificate-> select distribution -> upload CSR file which you have-> generate and download.

After downloading, double click on the profile which you just downloaded. Now you able to select provisioning profile in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the reason was that the "No certificates available" screen was secretly a loading screen. After waiting for ~1 minute, it changed to allow me to choose my Distribution certificate.

Answer (score 0):

May be the certificate you created were APNs certificate.You should create a development certificate.
APNs certificate is only for the purpose of push related use, thats why its not enough to create a provision.That may be issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the certificate using XCode (XCode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> View Details). After create, you will see the certificate on Portal