# No Certificates are available provisioning portal, create certificate

Tags: ios, push-notification, certificate, ios-provisioning

I have enabled push notification service for app. I am getting the following error when I try to create provisional profile for app distribution:

"No Certificates are available.
Click "Create Certificate." to create a Certificate. You need a Certificate to configure a Provisioning Profile."

Even i create certificate .

Any ideas?

Comment: Please see my answer on the similar question there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35427653/3006185

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, Solved by going in XCODE -> Preference -> Accounts -> selected the Account I want to publish my app with -> Manage Certificates,  Here I found that there is no Distribution certificate ! but I have it in Apple Developer Portal ! so simply I tapped the small plus button at the bottom, selected App Store, and XCODE created that certificate Automatically, and I can now see that certificate when I'm creating Provisioning profile.

[image]

Hope that helps.

Comment: this was my solution after changed my macbook pro.

Comment: @AlejandroDG glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

If you create a provisioning profile for Distribution, you need a Distribution certificate. Go to the certificates section (in the iOS Dev Center) and check that you don't only have "iOS Development" certificates, but also an "iOS Distribution" certificate. If you don't have it, you need to create it.

[image: Many iOS Development certificates, one iOS Distribution certificate]

Comment: i did it , Distribution certificate showing in certificate list, but there is no change

Comment: Are you creating on the iOS Dev Center or in XCode?

Comment: See what i am doing 

1. Creating App id . In this enabling Push Notification

2.  In Identifier list just configuring that app id for push notification

3. Creating certificate : In this I am selecting the "Apple Push notification service SSL(Production)" . Then selecting app id after that uploading the .certSigningRequest   file this step giving me distribution certificate

4. Provision profile :  In This step I am selecting App store ==> app Id ==> here I got "  No certificate are available " even certificate showing in list

Comment: The certificate for "Apple Push notification service SSL (production)" is a certificate for you server: when you want from your server to send push notification, you need this certificate to authenticate with APN server. So that's wrong for creating a provisioning profile for an app: You need to select "App Store and Ad Hoc".

Comment: Please see my answer on the similar question there: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35427653/3006185